# MAUI App needs double clicks to open from task bar when minimized on Windows 11, need to open it in single click like other apps

Tags: maui, windows-11

We have an MAUI application, it needs double clicks to open (maximize) from the taskbar on Windows 11, we need to open it in a single click like other applications, any suggestions would be of great help. On Windows 10, its is working fine.

Thanks you!

Comment: Sorry, I could not reproduce this problem on my side. I could open my maui app in a single click from the task bar after I minimized my maui app. The version of my computer is Window 11 Enterprise.